# CAGR on ratio variables

Tags: regression

I would like to know CAGR() on ratio variables is possible. 
For example, A = num of item sold / number of customers, and I have series of A ratios for five years. 
Then, is it okey if predict sixth year of ratio A using CAGR?

[image: cagr]

Comment: Could you explain why you think CAGR (computing a compound annual growth rate) would be problematic for ratio variables?

Comment: @whuber I found CAGR of values(e.g. num of customers), so I want to make sure. Would it be same result if I apply CAGR to denominator and nominator respectively?